# PdfSharpCore degrading the quality of my JPG input image

Tags: c#, .net-core, pdfsharp

I want to convert a JPG to a PDF. After some research, I found that you can do this using PDFsharp, and since I'm using C# .Net 5.0, I Nu*got* PdfSharpCore 1.2.11.

After some research I came up with the following code:

```cs
public void Convert(string inputFilePath, string targetFilePathTemplate, string title)
{
    using var document = new PdfDocument();
    document.Info.Author = "Me";
    document.Info.Title = title;
    document.Info.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
    document.Info.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
    document.Info.Subject = title;
    
    var page = document.AddPage();
    using (var image = XImage.FromFile(inputFilePath))
    {
        page.Width = image.PixelWidth;
        page.Height = image.PixelHeight;
        using var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
        gfx.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight);
    }
    document.Save($"{targetFilePathTemplate}.pdf");
}
```

However, it seems PdfSharpCore decides to degrade the quality of my JPG without asking...
[image]
You can also see the filesize of the JPG being ~1MB and the pdf being ~400kB.

Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try to set the image dpi resolution before doing the DrawImage

Comment: @TaW to my understanding, it is not required when setting the `page` `Width` and `Height` manually.

Comment: It should be noted that the original PDFsharp does not degrade the quality of images. The image handling is completely different in the port known as PdfSharpCore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XImage.FromFile(inputFilePath)` specifies the default quality level of 75.

If instead you call [`ImageSource.FromFile`](https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore/blob/b53a41424db93a8f324f7770b7fafafff42cfe1b/PdfSharpCore/Drawing/XImage.cs#L88) (passing in the quality level) then
[`XImage.FromImageSource`](https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore/blob/b53a41424db93a8f324f7770b7fafafff42cfe1b/PdfSharpCore/Drawing/ImageSource.cs#L35) then you can increase the quality level.

The image is unlikely to look *exactly* the same - but bumping it up to 85 or 90 will likely improve its rendering.

Comment: Great! However, `var imageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(inputFilePath, 95);` throws a NullReferenceException for me... so I'll have to confirm this...

Comment: Found it. I had to add an `ImageSource.ImageSourceImpl = new ImageSharpImageSource<Rgba32>();` somewhere. Now my pdf looks noice

Answer (score 0):

I found @mjwills answer very useful but wanted to add some details.

As @HBonarius mentionned in his comment, when you try to use `ImageSource.FromFile()` it throws

> System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

as described in this [Github issue](https://github.com/groege/PdfSharpCore/issues/16).

It seems you need to do an initialization of `ImageSource.ImageSourceImpl` prior of using `ImageSource.FromFile()`

```
public void Convert(string inputFilePath, string targetFilePathTemplate, string title)
{
    using var document = new PdfDocument();
    document.Info.Author = "Me";
    document.Info.Title = title;
    document.Info.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
    document.Info.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
    document.Info.Subject = title;
    var page = document.AddPage();

    ImageSource.ImageSourceImpl = new PdfSharpCore.Utils.ImageSharpImageSource<Rgba32>();
    var imgSrc = ImageSource.FromFile(inputFilePath, 80);   //Quality 80%
    
    using (var image = XImage.FromImageSource(imgSrc))
    {
        page.Width = image.PixelWidth;
        page.Height = image.PixelHeight;
        using var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
        gfx.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight);
    }
    document.Save($"{targetFilePathTemplate}.pdf");
}
```

[Credit](https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore/issues/18#issuecomment-419277605)